# Getting a response from database after table update

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

I have an application developed in `C#` and `Sql Server 2008`.

Here user can open a listing from database and at that time same database table is updated indicating the particular user has opened the current listing. When another user trying to open the same listing, the user will be notified saying user A has already opened the listing and have two options close or notify user.

In the notify user process I have to periodically check the database for every user who have opened a listing to find whether any of other user have send notification indicating they also trying to open the same listing.

Is there any smarter way of identify as soon as someone press send notification option, rather than periodically checking on the database. Something like getting a notification from database to the system? I did found about [SqlNotificationRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ht3391b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Is there any new feature in SQL 2008 which is similar?

Is it possible to achieve or any other alternative?

Comment: What are you using to talk against the database. Are you using some kind of ORM? Or just SQL inside the code

Comment: I am not using ORM, just ADO.NET.

Comment: But now you are checking every 1 min or so if there are users that are holding the table? Isn't it possible to do when the other user tries to commit?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a homogenous Microsoft infrastructure, you might want to check out the [SQL Server Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx).

The service Broker uses Queues to send messages to anyone who interested in its notifications. Your application can subscribe to these message and then react corresponding to the kind the change.

> SQL Server Service Broker provides native support for messaging and
>   queuing applications in the SQL Server Database Engine. This makes it
>   easier for developers to create sophisticated applications that use
>   the Database Engine components to communicate between disparate
>   databases. Developers can use Service Broker to easily build
>   distributed and reliable applications.

More about it here: [An Introduction to SQL Server Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

> With Service Broker, a feature in Microsoft SQL Server 2005, internal
>   or external processes can send and receive guaranteed, asynchronous
>   messages by using extensions to Transact-SQL Data Manipulation
>   Language (DML). Messages can be sent to a queue in the same database
>   as the sender, to another database in the same SQL Server instance, or
>   to another SQL Server instance either on the same server or on a
>   remote server.

Comment: +1 I think a persistent MSMQ is the way to go here for offline users. but I'm not sure if it needs to be on the db server. you could also look at other brokers inside your app. here is a good link to DotNetMQ. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193611/DotNetMQ-A-Complete-Message-Queue-System-for-NET

Answer (score 0):

I guess it totally depends on your approach.

If you do it by just querying. The database has no way to known what table is currently viewing by what user. Your application does however, and that must be the manager to say which table is currently viewed by which user and how can view and edit, etc.

If you use something like a common service with DataReader objects (SqlDataReader) you could count all the instances of your class managing those SqlDataReader and their last queries or so.

The data reader has an open connection to the resultset of the database. Maybe thats a lead?

This whole problem is equal to that of how many users are viewing a website? Once loaded, how do you know if they are still viewing it?